# ActiveMQ Artemis: Muticast address deliver messages inconsistently

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

We're using Artemis 2.19.0 and distributing XML messages.Recently, we found that some messages might get lost when sending them to a multicast address which has two durable multicast queues bound, those two durable queues both have a XPATH filter.

E.g.:

1. Create a multicast address named: **IN.ADDRESS.FOO**
2. Create two durable queues under it named: **IN.QUEUE1.FOO** and **IN.QUEUE2.FOO**
3. Set a XPATH filter to both queues: **XPATH '/XML/DATA/Direction[text()="Right"]'**
4. Send 1000 same matched XML messages to address **IN.ADDRESS.FOO** (With JMS and message size 20kb)

Somehow, **IN.QUEUE1.FOO** or **IN.QUEUE2.FOO** or both won't receive 1000 messages eventually.

We've tired to remove filter from one of them, then everything works fine, both queue will receive 1000 messages.

1. We're using a HA architecture with one alive node and one back-up node.
2. We've checked the DLQ and nothing there, so it should not be a max-redelivery-attempt exceeded.
3. This behaviour happens even with no consumer connect.

So, my question is:

1. Could it be the reason that a XML filter **it may be significantly slower than normal filters** that cause some messages get lost?
2. If not what could be the reason?

If you have anything unclear, please ask.
Thanks

**UPDATE 1:**

Versions:

```
Java: 1.8
Spring-Integration: 5.5.11
Spring-jms: 5.3.19
Artemis: 2.19.0
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:int-xml="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml"
             xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
             xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
             xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.3.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms-4.3.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml/spring-integration-xml-4.3.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file-4.3.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.3.xsd">
    <!-- Multicast address -->
    <beans:bean id="topic" class="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQTopic">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="IN.ADDRESS.FOO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Anycast queue -->
    <beans:bean id="queue" class="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQQueue">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="AQ.QUEUE.FOO"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <channel id="topicChannel">
    </channel>

    <task:executor id="executor" pool-size="2"/>

    <publish-subscribe-channel id="outChannel" task-executor="executor"/>

    <filter id="consumer1" input-channel="outChannel" output-channel="topicChannel" expression="payload.length() > 0"/>

    <filter id="consumer2" input-channel="outChannel" output-channel="topicChannel" expression="payload.length() > 0"/>

    <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="queueAdapter" destination="queue" channel="outChannel"
                                        acknowledge="auto" connection-factory="ConnectionFactory"/>

    <jms:outbound-channel-adapter  id="topicAdapter" destination="topic" channel="topicChannel"
                                  connection-factory="ConnectionFactory"/>


</beans:beans>
```

ConnectionFactory Bean:

```
@Bean(name = "ConnectionFactory")
    public SingleConnectionFactory ibConnectionFactory(
            @Value("${artemis.broker-url}") String brokerUrl,
            @Value("${artemis.user}") String username,
            @Value("${artemis.password}") String password) throws JMSException {

        ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        factory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
        factory.setUser(username);
        factory.setPassword(password);
        return new SingleConnectionFactory(factory);
    }
```

Sender program:

```
try(ActiveMQConnectionFactory fac = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrl, user, password)) {
            Connection conn = fac.createConnection();
            Session session = conn.createSession();
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(new ActiveMQQueue("AQ.QUEUE.FOO"));
            Message msg = session.createTextMessage("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Root xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><Data><PrimaryKey><Key><DetailedIdentity><ATCode>AK</ATCode></DetailedIdentity></Key></PrimaryKey></Data></Root>");

            int count = 0;
            while (count < 1000) {
                System.out.println(count);
                producer.send(msg);
                count ++;
            }
        }
```

XPATH Filter:

```
XPATH '/Root/Data/PrimaryKey/Key/DetailedIdentity/ATCode[text()="AK"]'
```

Message Sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Data><PrimaryKey><Key><DetailedIdentity><ATCode>AK</ATCode></DetailedIdentity></Key></PrimaryKey></Data></Root>
```

Either remove the task-executor attribute on publish-subscribe-channel or remove one of the queue's filter fix the problem.

**UPDATE 2:**

A minimal example with 10 concurrent tasks sending 1000 messages in total, if all the queues under the same address both have the XPATH filter then it would not receive 1000 messages, but with removing one of the filter it works.

```
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQTopic;

import javax.jms.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


public class TestRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String brokerUrl = "(tcp://server1:61616,tcp://server2:61616)?ha=true&reconnectAttempts=-1&retryInterval=100&retryIntervalMultiplier=1.5&maxRetryInterval=6000";
        String user = "admin";
        String password = "admin";

        ActiveMQConnectionFactory fac = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrl, user, password);
        ExecutorService ser = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            ser.submit(() -> {
                Connection conn = null;
                try {
                    conn = fac.createConnection();
                    Session session = conn.createSession();
                    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(new ActiveMQTopic("IN.ADDRESS.FOO"));
                    Message msg = session.createTextMessage("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Root xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><Data><PrimaryKey><Key><DetailedIdentity><ATCode>AK</ATCode></DetailedIdentity></Key></PrimaryKey></Data></Root>");
                    int count = 0;
                    while (count < 100) {
                        System.out.println(count);
                        msg.setStringProperty("MessageId", String.valueOf(count));
                        producer.send(msg);
                        count++;
                    }
                    session.close();
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @JustinBertram Hi, justin. Sorry for the delay, i've worked out a minimal example which could reproduce the scenario, please check, thanks.

Comment: @JustinBertram Hi justin, a new example is updated, i don't know if it's the right way to use concurrent producer, but i think it's quite the same scenario as the spring example above, please check it out, much appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the test-case. I was able to use it to reproduce the error you were seeing. I opened [ARTEMIS-4687](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-4687) and sent [a PR](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/pull/4852) to fix the issue. This will be fixed in 2.33.0 release which is due in the next few weeks.

Comment: Hi, justin. As i checked the PR, is the synchronized builder the final resolution? I mean if there is a high throughput, then each thread will waiting for the resource and causing the process even slower, maybe maintain the DocumentBuilder as a ThreadLocal variable?

Comment: Synchronizing access to `builder` is one possible solution to the problem, but it's not the only one, of course. Although it may negatively impact performance this solution does have the benefit of being the simplest one I considered. If complaints arise that the synchronization is problematic then other solutions can be considered. I tend to adhere to the tenet that "premature optimization is the root of all evil." To be clear, this is not a commonly used feature. Pull requests are certainly welcome if you have a better solution. 